# Separating a String with index of

Tags: java, eclipse, indexof

I'm trying to take one whole string, and print each section of it differently using index of.
I've been trying something like this...

```
String example = "one, two, three, four"
int comma = example.indexOf(',' , 0);
    String output = example.substring(comma);
    System.out.println(output);
```

This prints

```
,two,three,four
```

I can't get it to do anything else...

Comment: You need to use a `loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only using `indexOf` method with `loop` you can print all separate `String` separated by comma `,`. You don't need `split` regex. Look at following example.

```
    String str = "one, two, three, four";
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int firstIndex=0;
    while (lastIndex != -1) {

        lastIndex = str.indexOf(',', lastIndex);

        if (lastIndex != -1) {
            System.out.print(str.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex));

            if(lastIndex==str.lastIndexOf(',')){
            System.out.print(str.substring(lastIndex));
            }
            lastIndex += 1;
        }

        firstIndex=lastIndex;
    }
    System.out.println();
```

**Output:** one two three four

Comment: Thanks! I just added \n to make it new lines.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
String example = "one, two, three, four";

for (int i = example.indexOf(", "); i != -1; i = example.indexOf(", ")) {
    System.out.println(example.substring(0, i));
    example = example.substring(i + 2);
}
System.out.println(example);
```

if you like recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "one, two, three, four";
    printSections(example);
}

public static void printSections(String word) {
    int i = word.indexOf(", ");
    if (i == -1) System.out.println(word);
    else {
        System.out.println(word.substring(0, i));
        printSections(word.substring(i + 2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with `split()`?

```
String example = "one, two, three, four"
String[] temp = example.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<temp.length; i++){
System.out.println(temp[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the indexOf method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy method in String class. [`Sting#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

You just split your string with comma, that is all what you need.

```
String example = "one, two, three, four";
String[] split = example.split(",");
for (String string : split) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

split method returns the `array` of separated and string's and we just need to print them.

Side note: I used [`Enhanced for loop to iterate`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/enhanced-for-loops.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the indexOf method.

Comment: Using `indexOf` with loop also possible to separate `String`.

Comment: @Masud Yes, single problem may have number of possible solutions. I no where write that *not possible*

Answer (score 0):

Use Split

```
String example = "one, two, three, four";
    for(String i:example.split(",")){
        System.out.println(i);

    }
```

Using IndexOf

```
    String example = "one, two, three, four";
    String output;
    String temp = example;
    int gIndex = 0;
    int len = example.length();
    example += ",";
    for(int i=0 ; i<len;i+=gIndex+1){
        gIndex = example.indexOf(",");
        output = example.substring(0,gIndex);
        System.out.println(output);
        example = example.replace(output, "").replaceFirst(",", "");
    }
    example = temp;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the indexOf method.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
String example = "one, two, three, four"
String[] output = example.split(',');
for(String s:output){  
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the indexOf method.